# Snowflake Auto Ingest not working while pipe loads fine on refresh

Tags: amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, amazon-sns

We have a Snowflake pipe on a S3 integration which is setup to auto-ingest using a SNS topic dedicated to object creation events on the S3 bucket, following [Snowflake documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-auto-s3.html#option-2-configuring-amazon-sns-to-automate-snowpipe-using-sqs-notifications)

While loading data by refreshing the pipe works perfectly, it seems that SNS subscription triggered by creation of the pipe setting `aws_sns_topic` to the topic ARN and `auto_ingest = true` does not work since after creation of the pipe, we cannot see the SNS->SQS subscription.

We have used this pattern many times and all the existing ones work perfectly except this one. Also, I should mention that the infrastructure in AWS is created with Terraform. Finally, the pipe is created (or replaced) after any changes to the SNS topic. I am happy to post my IAM policy on the role assigned to SFK for a second look but I have made sure it does have `sns:Subscribe` on the SNS topic.

Note: We have tried direct direct S3 event notification bucket to SQS subscription as proposed by [Snowflake docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-auto-s3.html#option-1-creating-a-new-s3-event-notification-to-automate-snowpipe) and that did not help either.

Comment: I believe I am seeing something similar, including occasional instances where existing snowpipes that were once working fine require a refresh to resume working.  Also using terraform here. Did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. IIRC, we just recreated our whole stack to make it work again, but it was some time ago so the details have escaped me.

Comment: Thanks. I suspect the pipe has to be recreated, but this has to be done at least 72 hours since the SNS subscription was deleted. Or, to avoid the 72 hour window, re-create the pipe with a different name.